# CDP not visible in Sandbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, salesforce-cdp

We want to use CDP (Customer Data Platform) in our Sandbox but we can only see it in production ORG. We checked all the permissions. Connected Sandbox to production in CDP setup but nothing showed up. But we can see permission sets.

Had someone same problem? Did you find any solution for using CDP in Sandbox ORG?

Thank you for your answers .

Comment: In order to get the Salesforce CDP app in your sandbox, you need to refresh your Sandbox. Refreshing Sandbox will pull all the data and metadata from Production into Sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change! Official Salesforce support stated that there is NO sandbox version of Salesforce CDP.